# SharePoint 2013 - User Profile synchronisation and appfabric error

Tags: user-profile-service, app-fabric

I try to start the User Profile Synchronisation service, it starts but then stops again.

When I press "start", the Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service is up and set up correctly but appfabric goes down.

In the job history I have this error :

> FeedCacheService.IsRepopulationNeeded: SPDistributedCache don't work

In the services: Appfabric is down

And in event log: id 1000

After a moment the service Forefront Identity Manager Synchronization Service goes down and appfabric goes up.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: did you check if Distributed cache is working? check this technet.https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219613.aspx ...If you share the compelte error details that really help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is resolved

The cause was: The clock skew between the SharePoint server and DNS server

Correcting this solved the issue